# Looking to connect the nodes that are at a certain maximum distance R in Networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I want to take the number of nodes **"N"** from the user and plot them randomly in a 2D surface MxM.
Next is to connect nodes say **i,j ∈ N** *if and only if* their distance R is <= to any constant threshold.

```
G = nx.DiGraph()

n_size=input("Please enter number of nodes: ")
n_size = int(n_size)

for i in range(n_size):
    G.add_node(i)

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6))
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, font_weight='normal')
plt.axis('on')
plt.show()
```

Comment: How are the nodes positioned?  In `NetworkX`, the node layout is not static and will change every time the nodes are drawn unless their position is specified.  Are you wanting nodes to be in a grid-type layout or do you want the positions to be randomized and then connect them if that random distance is less than your desired threshold?

Comment: Thank You @Andrew. I want nodes to be randomly placed and then calculate the distance between all nodes and make edges between all nodes having a distance more than the threshold. I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of options to consider.  For both of them, your beginning block of code is the same:

```
G = nx.DiGraph()

n_size=input("Please enter number of nodes: ")
n_size = int(n_size)

for i in range(n_size):
    G.add_node(i)

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6))
```

The positions of the nodes need to be determined in advance of creating edges, however, so you have to use one of the [`NetworkX` layouts](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/drawing.html#module-networkx.drawing.layout) to do that.  Since you mentioned wanting a random node layout, that's what I'll be using here, but there are many other options.  I'll also add a threshold value for the distance of 0.3 that will be used later.

```
pos = nx.random_layout(G)
threshold = 0.3
```

This creates a position dictionary with node names as keys and coordinates as values.  As far as the actual options for creating edges based on a distance threshold, you could do one of the following.

**Using built-in `nx.geometric_edges`**

`NetworkX` has a convenient [`geometric_edges`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.generators.geometric.geometric_edges.html) function that takes a threshold distance value and returns a list of edges for nodes that fall within that distance from one another.

The `geometric_edges` function requires that each node have a `pos` attribute associated with it, so we can add that as follows:

```
for node_name in G.nodes:
    G.node[node_name]['pos'] = pos[node_name]
```

This just takes the value from the position dictionary and adds it to each node of the graph as a `pos` attribute.

Next, we can simply use the `geometric_edges` method, which returns a list of edges that are less than a specified distance from one another.  There is also a `p` argument required for the method that defaults to a value of 2 if no other value is specified.  2 indicates Euclidean distance, which I'm assuming is what you want, so I'll leave the default as is.

```
edges_to_add_list = nx.geometric_edges(G, threshold, p = 2)
G.add_edges_from(edges_to_add_list)
```

This method only creates an edge in one direction in a directed graph, so you'd need to add reversed edges if you need them to be bi-directional.

**Manually calculating distance**
If you'd like to have a bit more flexibility to only select nodes that are above (rather than below) a certain distance from one another, you can calculate the distance and add edges yourself.  This will add edges in both directions between nodes and can show self-loops as well if you want it to.  This method assumes you have `numpy` installed as `np`.

```
for node_a in G.nodes:
    for node_b in G.nodes:
        if np.sqrt((pos[node_a][0]-pos[node_b][0])**2 + (pos[node_a][1]-pos[node_b][1])**2) <= threshold and node_a != node_b:
            G.add_edge(node_a, node_b)
```

If you want self-loops to show up, just eliminate the `node_a != node_b` part.
Here's just an example of the second method with 15 nodes:
[image: networkx nodes connected based on distance]

Comment: Thanks once again @Andrew. with very minute modification your answer worked well for me. I really appreciate the detailed answer.